# Ajax Document Upload only firing the first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to upload a File with Ajax.
The Problem is, it works only the first time.

After the first Document is uploaded the $.ajax doenst fire anymore.
The Submit Handler gets fired but not the Ajax Function.

```
$( 'form#addDocument' ).on('submit', function( event ){

    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();

    $( 'form#addDocument' ).spin('progress');

    var file = $("#addDocumentFileInput").prop("files")[0];    
    var formData = new FormData();

    formData.append("file", file)
    formData.append("filename", $( '#documentName' ).val() );

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'index.php?r=ajax/uploaddocument',
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'script',
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function( data ){
            if ( data == 'true' ) {
                showInformation(succ);
            }
        },
        complete: function(){
            $( 'form#addDocument' ).spin(false);
            $('form#addDocument')[0].reset();
            closeOverlay();
            reloadDocs();
        },
    });
});
```

The `reloadDocs()` in the complete function manipulates the Content, but the Overlay and the form isn't affected of that.

The `closeOverlay()` fades out the overlay.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors on the second submission? Are you sure it's the `$.ajax` call that's failing and not something server side?

Comment: Yes, there arent any errors! i also placed logging before and after the ajax call. The ajax doesnt show up in the console ( i use firebug )

Comment: Also i got many other Ajax calls on the same site and script who doesnt have a problem with firing twice ...

Comment: please provide code on jsfiddle

Comment: Have you tried removing the `dataType` ? I may be very wrong but it's worth a try

Comment: Removing the datatype fixed the problem ... thanks!